# How do I use a function inside another function's function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to capitalize the first letter of each word in the other function.

This is the function to turn each words first letter to capital that I am using.

```
function capital_letter(str) 
{
    str = str.split(" ");

    for (var i = 0, x = str.length; i < x; i++) {
        str[i] = str[i][0].toUpperCase() + str[i].substr(1);
    }

    return str.join(" ");
}
```

Here’s the second function that I’m trying to use the first one in, but it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#list').dataTable({
    "ajax":{
          url :"list.php",
          type: "GET",
          error: function(){
            $("#post_list_processing").css("display","none");
          }
        },
        "columns": [
              { "data": function capital_letter(item) {
                  return item.title;
                }
              },
              { "data": "description" },
              { "data": "time" }
          ]
  });
});
```

Comment: You're not calling the function, you're redefining it.  Should be `"data": capital_letter(item.title),`  (or `item`, whichever contains the text you want to modify)

Comment: Try to define the function outside and call it inside from the another function

Comment: Can you put your code on codepen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only call the function like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#list').dataTable({
    ajax: {
      url: 'list.php',
      type: 'GET',
      error: function() {
        $('#post_list_processing').css('display', 'none');
      },
    },
    columns: [{
        data: capital_letter(item.title);

      },
      { data: 'description' },
      { data: 'time' },
    ],
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're redefining the function instead of actually using it... Call it like this;

```
...
"columns": [
    { "data": capital_letter(item.title) }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the function correctly. Change the following in your code.

```
"columns": [
    { "data": capital_letter(item.title) }
```

Created a working snippet.

```js
function capital_letter(str) {
  str = str.split(" ");

  for (var i = 0, x = str.length; i < x; i++) {
    str[i] = str[i][0].toUpperCase() + str[i].substr(1);
  }

  return str.join(" ");
}

const columns = [{
    "data": capital_letter("abc")
  },
  {
    "data": "description"
  },
  {
    "data": "time"
  }
]

console.log(columns)
```